# Probability distributions as limits of continuous ones and of discrete ones

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

While skipping through the class notes I noticed one exercice that I couldn't solve:

Suppose we have $\mu$ - probability distribution in $\mathbb{R}$.

Recalling that  $\mu_k \rightarrow \mu$ iff $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\mu_k(dx) \rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \mu(dx)$, $\forall f \in C(\mathbb{R})$, $f$ bounded $k\rightarrow \infty$. We have to show:

1. $\exists \mu_k$ - series of continuous distributions that $\mu_k \rightarrow \mu$.
2. $\exists \mu_k$ - series of discrete distributions that $\mu_k \rightarrow \mu$.

Comment: Hint: Look at the cdfs.  If $\mu_k, \mu$ are probability distributions with cdfs $F_k, F$, recall $\mu_k \to \mu$ weakly iff $F_k(x) \to F(x)$ at all points $x$ where $F$ is continuous.  Can you approximate $F$ in this sense by continuous cdfs?  By cdfs which are step functions?

Comment: We didn't actually had the weak convergence defined in our classes, so I guess the only thing we can use here is that  $\mu_k \rightarrow \mu$ iff $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\mu_k(dx) \rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \mu(dx)$, $\forall f \in C(\mathbb{R})$, $k\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Which properties of weak convergence do you know?

Comment: The only thing we know is the fact that was mentioned above.

Comment: Your definition should say "...for all *bounded*, continuous functions $f$..."

Comment: You're right! It's just we use $C$ notation for continuous and bounded, that's my mistake. I actually did prove that but my solution requires two cases for each task (for continuous and discrete cases), but I wonder is there universal solution for both continuous and discrete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

- Every distribution is a barycenter $p\mu_d+(1-p)\mu_c$ where $0\leqslant p\leqslant1$, $\mu_d$ is discrete and $\mu_c$ is continuous.
- As a consequence, it suffices to show that every discrete distribution is a limit of continuous ones, and vive versa.
- In one direction, show that, for every $x$, the (continuous) uniform distribution on the interval $[x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon]$ converges to the (discrete) Dirac distribution at $x$ when $\varepsilon\to0^+$.
- In the other direction, show that, for every continuous distribution $\mu_c$, the (discrete) distribution $\sum\limits_n\mu_c([n\varepsilon,(n+1)\varepsilon))\,\delta_{n\varepsilon}$, where the sum runs over every integer $n$, converges to $\mu_c$ when $\varepsilon\to0^+$.